# Removing router login from localhost?

Tags: windows, windows-7, localhost, router

I have an Technicolor TG789vn v3 modem and it have built in router, which I don't need at all.
So by going to my localhost I see router login page. 
Using xampp on windows 7 btw.
And since it's nice to play with small pages on local I would be more than happy to remove this router login from my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out it was the wrong IP I was accessing.
How to find your real IP: [Microsoft sometimes actually helps.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/find-computers-ip-address#1TC=windows-7)